JOIN statement creating duplicate rows
I have this SQL query:
WITH featured_items
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT cfpi.sku_no,
                         Max(pm.itemsource)
                           OVER (
                             ORDER BY pm.itemsource DESC)
                            itemsource,
                         cm.categoryid,
                         Substr(cm.categoryname, Instr(cm.categoryname, '-') + 1
                         )
                            cat_name
         FROM   category_feat_pick_items cfpi
                JOIN pricemaster pm
                  ON cfpi.sku_no = pm.sku_no
                JOIN categorymaster cm
                  ON cfpi.categoryid = cm.categoryid
         WHERE  cfpi.categoryid = 35801),
     attributes_to_use
     AS (SELECT cfpc.categoryid,
                cfpc.attributeid,
                am.attributename,
                sequence attribute_sequence
         FROM   category_feat_pick_comp cfpc
                JOIN attributemaster am
                  ON cfpc.attributeid = am.attributeid
         WHERE  attribute_option <> 'H'
                AND statusflag <> 'D'
                AND categoryid = 35801),
     compared_items
     AS (SELECT categoryid,
                sku_no,
                itemsource,
                attributeid,
                valueid,
                am.attributename,
                av.valuestring,
                sequence                                  attribute_sequence,
                cat_name,
                Count(DISTINCT sku_no)
                  OVER (
                    partition BY categoryid)              item_count,
                Count(DISTINCT sku_no)
                  OVER (
                    partition BY categoryid, attributeid) att_item_count
         FROM   featured_items s
                JOIN category_feat_pick_comp cfpc using (categoryid)
                JOIN inventorymaster_attributevalue ia using (sku_no,
                attributeid)
                JOIN attributemaster am using (attributeid)
                JOIN attributevalue av using (attributeid, valueid)
                JOIN attributes_to_use atu using (attributeid, categoryid)
         WHERE  ia.statusflag <> 'D')
SELECT *
FROM   compared_items; 

Which returns these two rows:



SKU_NO
ATTRIBUTE_ID
VALUE_ID
ATTRIBUTE_NAME
VALUE_STRING




1722157
1
100
ATTR_1
VALUE_1


1722157
2
200
ATTR_2
VALUE_2



The issue is that the SKU_NO is the same, meaning it's the same item, but since some issue in the JOIN (I assume) it's giving two rows because there are two attributes. What I need is to JOIN but have each attribute be it's own column, and each value also be it's own column like this:



SKU_NO
ATTR_1
ATTR_2




1722157
VALUE_1
VALUE_2



Does anyone know where the issue is happening? I assume it's at the JOIN statements, but I'm not sure.

A SQL query results in a table of the columns you state in your query (e.g. ATTRIBUTE_NAME and VALUE_STRING) and a variable number of rows. It won't create a result table with a variable number of columns. If you want to display the result in that manner, you should call the SQL from an app or webite and then use its programming language to loop through the SQL result and create that grid.

look for pivot query, conditional aggregation; are there a small fixed number of ATTRIBUTE_NAME values?

What do you mean?

ysth means that if there exist only few attribute names and you know them at the time when you write the query, you can write a query that has one column for each known value. If for instance the only possible attributes are 'ATTR_1' and 'ATTR_2', then you can provide these two columns in the query. The keywords to look up how to do this are "pivot" or "conditional aggregation".

Why do you have 3 CTEs when you are only selecting from 1?  Makes reading your query  needlessly complex.  Most likely you are getting two rows back because for this sku, you have 2 rows in attributemaster.  It may not be an issue in the join.  It's your data, we can't answer that without sample data, etc.
